# Triple integral question

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

In a textbook problem, I am asked to find the flux through a given surface using the divergence theorem. That is, $$\iiint_{G} \nabla \cdot \vec{F} \, dV = \iint_{\sigma} \vec{F} \cdot \vec{n} \, dS$$

Given $\vec{F} = x^3\hat{i} + y^3\hat{j} + z^3\hat{k}$, find the flux through the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 4$ lying below $z=3$ and above $z=0$.

**My solution**

Simply, $\nabla \cdot \vec{F} = 3x^2\hat{i} + 3y^2\hat{j} + 3z^2\hat{k}$. Substituting this into the integral, we obtain

\begin{align*}
 \iiint_{G} \nabla \cdot \vec{F} \, dV &= 
\iiint_{G} 3x^2\hat{i} + 3y^2\hat{j} + 3z^2\hat{k} \, dV \\ 
&= \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2} \int_{0}^{3} 3z^2 + 3r^2 dz dr d\theta \\  
&\vdots \\
&= 156 \pi                   
\end{align*}

however, the book gives a solution of $180 \pi$. Why is this?

Comment: I've edited the array; please make sure it still says what you intended.

Comment: You are missing a $r$ from the Jacobian.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have the correct volume form for cylindrical coordinates: You should integrate against $r dr d\theta dz$, similar to polar coordinates. (That is, the volume form $dx dy dz$ is given by $r dr d\theta dz$ in cylindrical coordinates, because the Jacobian is $r$.) Then the integral becomes

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^2 \int_0^3 3z^2 r + 3r^3 dz dr d\theta$$

This indeed gives $180 \pi$.

Comment: If the downvoter would offer a correction or improvement, I'd be happy to hear it.